# How to unit test when a view changes?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Currently I'm trying to test some simple functions:

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var sampleView: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
  }
      func hideView() {
        sampleView.isHidden = true
      }

      func showView() {
        sampleView.isHidden = false
      }
}
```

Here are the test cases:

```
import XCTest
@testable import unitUITestPractice

class unitUITestPracticeTests: XCTestCase {

  var sut: SampleViewController?

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

       sut = SampleViewController()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
     sut = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

  func test_hideView() {
    sut?.hideView()
    XCTAssertNil(sut?.sampleView)
  }

  func test_showView() {
    sut?.showView()
    XCTAssertNotNil(sut?.sampleView)
  }
}
```

The issue is I keep getting the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

when it tries and run the function in the tests case:

```
func hideView() {
    sampleView.isHidden = true //error here
  }
```

Does anyone know a better way to test whether a view has changed?

Comment: you need to instantiate the viewController through storyboard,  `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIdentifier") as! SampleViewController`. Also, the view will never be nil when instantiated properly, in this case you want to test against the views `isHidden` property, checking for `true` or `false`

Comment: As @JustinM suggested create viewController. You have to load the view in memory. So do either `viewController.viewdidLoad() or viewController.view`. then all the view elements (sampleView) will have a value. Then you have to assert the properties of that view. (in your case visibility/hidden of sampleView)

Comment: You have an outlet. Is your view controller coming from a storyboard, or from a xib file?